# Error messages when installing package from file

Tags: r, install.packages

Receiving unusual error messages when installing an R package directly from a file - https://pm2.phs.ed.ac.uk/genoscores/:

```
In file included from RcppExports.cpp:4:
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/library/RcppEigen/include/RcppEigen.h:25:
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/library/RcppEigen/include/RcppEigenForward.h:26:
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/library/Rcpp/include/RcppCommon.h:30:
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/r/headers.h:62:
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/platform/compiler.h:100:
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cmath:317:9: error: no member named 'signbit' in the global namespace
using ::signbit;
      ~~^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cmath:318:9: error: no member named 'fpclassify' in the global namespace
using ::fpclassify;
      ~~^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cmath:319:9: error: no member named 'isfinite' in the global namespace; did you mean 'finite'?
using ::isfinite;
      ~~^
/usr/local/include/math.h:749:12: note: 'finite' declared here
extern int finite(double)
           ^
In file included from RcppExports.cpp:4:
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/library/RcppEigen/include/RcppEigen.h:25:
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/library/RcppEigen/include/RcppEigenForward.h:26:
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/library/Rcpp/include/RcppCommon.h:30:
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/r/headers.h:62:
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/platform/compiler.h:100:
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cmath:320:9: error: no member named 'isinf' in the global namespace
using ::isinf;
      ~~^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cmath:321:9: error: no member named 'isnan' in the global namespace
using ::isnan;
      ~~^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cmath:322:9: error: no member named 'isnormal' in the global namespace
using ::isnormal;
      ~~^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cmath:323:9: error: no member named 'isgreater' in the global namespace
using ::isgreater;
      ~~^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cmath:324:9: error: no member named 'isgreaterequal' in the global namespace
using ::isgreaterequal;
      ~~^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cmath:325:9: error: no member named 'isless' in the global namespace
using ::isless;
      ~~^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cmath:326:9: error: no member named 'islessequal' in the global namespace
using ::islessequal;
      ~~^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cmath:327:9: error: no member named 'islessgreater' in the global namespace
using ::islessgreater;
      ~~^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cmath:328:9: error: no member named 'isunordered' in the global namespace
using ::isunordered;
      ~~^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cmath:329:9: error: no member named 'isunordered' in the global namespace
using ::isunordered;
      ~~^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cmath:640:26: error: no template named 'numeric_limits'
    bool _FloatBigger = (numeric_limits<_FloatT>::digits > numeric_limits<_IntT>::digits),
                         ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cmath:640:60: error: no template named 'numeric_limits'
    bool _FloatBigger = (numeric_limits<_FloatT>::digits > numeric_limits<_IntT>::digits),
                                                           ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cmath:641:18: error: no template named 'numeric_limits'
    int _Bits = (numeric_limits<_IntT>::digits - numeric_limits<_FloatT>::digits)>
                 ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cmath:641:50: error: no template named 'numeric_limits'
    int _Bits = (numeric_limits<_IntT>::digits - numeric_limits<_FloatT>::digits)>
                                                 ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cmath:646:17: error: no template named 'numeric_limits'
  static_assert(numeric_limits<_FloatT>::radix == 2, "FloatT has incorrect radix");
                ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cmath:649:25: error: no template named 'numeric_limits'
  return _FloatBigger ? numeric_limits<_IntT>::max() :  (numeric_limits<_IntT>::max() >> _Bits << _Bits);
                        ^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
20 errors generated.
make: *** [RcppExports.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘genoscores’
```

The package isn't available anywhere else.
I have all the dependencies.
I don't know where to start deciphering this, is it a problem with compilers?

Comment: What command are you running exactly that is producing those errors?

Comment: install.packages("~/path/to/genoscores_0.93.0.9000_R_x86_64-pc-linux-gnu.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source", lib="/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/library")